# How to use PHP to sort an array on a value within a nested namespace array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting, namespaces

I've generated an array from an xml file.  That file is information about videos from a number of youtube channels. I now want to sort the array by `video:publication_date` (descending) in PHP.  I aim to identify and display the latest 10 videos from all channels included in the xml file.

How can this be done?

I've seen a number of solutions that sort simple arrays but I can't work out how to get them to work sorting on values within a nested namespace array like `[video:video]` using PHP.

print_r($array) outputs something like the following:

```
Array
(
    [urlset] => Array
        (
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [loc] => http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxQSNyiwMk
                            [video:video] => Array
                                (
                                    [video:thumbnail_loc] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxQSNyiwMk/hqdefault.jpg
                                    [video:title] => Singing
                                    [video:description] => Show
                                    [video:player_loc] => http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxQSNyiwMk
                                    [video:duration] => 162
                                    [video:view_count] => 38
                                    [video:publication_date] => 2014-12-10T16:01:08.000Z
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [loc] => http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxeDipW7PU
                            [video:video] => Array
                                (
                                    [video:thumbnail_loc] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxeDipW7PU/hqdefault.jpg
                                    [video:title] => Singing Live
                                    [video:description] => Performing Nov.18th 2014
                                    [video:player_loc] => http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxeDipW7PU
                                    [video:duration] => 244
                                    [video:view_count] => 265
                                    [video:publication_date] => 2014-12-09T11:14:00.000Z
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [loc] => http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxyvRH4NEg
                            [video:video] => Array
                                (
                                    [video:thumbnail_loc] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxyvRH4NEg/hqdefault.jpg
                                    [video:title] => Making
                                    [video:description] => Performing Nov.15th 2015
                                    [video:player_loc] => http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxyvRH4NEg
                                    [video:duration] => 222
                                    [video:view_count] => 79
                                    [video:publication_date] => 2014-12-09T00:03:06.000Z
                                )

                        )
                    ....
```

Comment: Use `usort` and provide a comparison function that compares `$arg1['video:video']['video:publication_date']` with `$arg2['video:video']['video:publication_date']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following using [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) which requires a lower level associative array to sort the larger array. This solution even allows room for additional sort fields.

**Replicating array** (*notice I purposely misarranged the publication date for demonstration*):

```
$youtube = array();

$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['loc'] = "http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxyvRH4NEg";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:thumbnail_loc'] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxyvRH4NEg/hqdefault.jpg";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:title'] = "Making";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:description'] = "Performing Nov.15th 2015";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:player_loc'] = "http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxyvRH4NEg";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:duration'] =  222;
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:view_count'] = 79;
$youtube['urlset']['url'][0]['video:video']['video:publication_date'] = date("2014-12-09T00:03:06.000Z");

$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['loc'] = "http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxeDipW7PU";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:thumbnail_loc'] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxeDipW7PU/hqdefault.jpg";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:title'] = "Singing Live";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:description'] = "Performing Nov.18th 2014";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:player_loc'] = "http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxeDipW7PU";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:duration'] =  244;
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:view_count'] = 265;
$youtube['urlset']['url'][1]['video:video']['video:publication_date'] = date("2014-12-09T11:14:00.000Z");

$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['loc'] = "http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxQSNyiwMk";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:thumbnail_loc'] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxQSNyiwMk/hqdefault.jpg";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:title'] = "Singing";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:description'] = "Show";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:player_loc'] = "http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxQSNyiwMk";
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:duration'] = 162;
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:view_count'] = 38;
$youtube['urlset']['url'][2]['video:video']['video:publication_date'] = date("2014-12-10T16:01:08.000Z");
```

**Actual sort code**

```
# TO CREATE SORTING ARRAY, $pubdate
$pubdate = array();
foreach ($youtube['urlset']['url'] as $ykey => $yvalue) {        
    $pubdate[] = $yvalue['video:video']['video:publication_date'];
}

# APPLYING SORTING TO ARRAY AT URL LEVEL
array_multisort($pubdate, SORT_DESC, $youtube['urlset']['url']);
```

**Output** (*notice where 2014-12-10 was originally at bottom as URL[2] is now at top as URL[0] being the most recent date*)

```
Array
(
    [urlset] => Array
        (
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [loc] => http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxQSNyiwMk
                            [video:video] => Array
                                (
                                    [video:thumbnail_loc] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxQSNyiwMk/hqdefault.jpg
                                    [video:title] => Singing
                                    [video:description] => Show
                                    [video:player_loc] => http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxQSNyiwMk
                                    [video:duration] => 162
                                    [video:view_count] => 38
                                    [video:publication_date] => 2014-12-10CDT16:01:08.000-18000
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [loc] => http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxeDipW7PU
                            [video:video] => Array
                                (
                                    [video:thumbnail_loc] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxeDipW7PU/hqdefault.jpg
                                    [video:title] => Singing Live
                                    [video:description] => Performing Nov.18th 2014
                                    [video:player_loc] => http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxeDipW7PU
                                    [video:duration] => 244
                                    [video:view_count] => 265
                                    [video:publication_date] => 2014-12-09CDT11:14:00.000-18000
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [loc] => http://www. . . ./vod_page.php?channel=XXxxbnaoqvqbGpCcW9t3V1jQ&vid=xxxyvRH4NEg
                            [video:video] => Array
                                (
                                    [video:thumbnail_loc] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xxxyvRH4NEg/hqdefault.jpg
                                    [video:title] => Making
                                    [video:description] => Performing Nov.15th 2015
                                    [video:player_loc] => http://www. . . ./jw57player.swf?file=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxyvRH4NEg
                                    [video:duration] => 222
                                    [video:view_count] => 79
                                    [video:publication_date] => 2014-12-09CDT00:03:06.000-18000
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I think you can simplify the `foreach ($yvalue as $vkey => $vvalue) {...}` loop body to `$pubdate[] = $yvalue['video:video']['video:publication_date'];`

Comment: Great suggestion! But actually, your suggestion doubled for each date, leaving `$pubdate[]` with 6 date items. But removing the inner `foreach()` loop, it worked great! I appreciate it.